# Simple php script to run the java program and display the output on the webpage

Tags: java, php

I have written a simple java program which performs the addition of two numbers.

I need to run this java program from php and I need to give the two input numbers from this script and the output should be displayed in the webpage.

```
**java program:-**

import java.io.*;

class sum1

{

public static void main(String args[]) 

{

int a=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

int b=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

int c =a + b;

System.out.println(c);

}

}
```

**PHP script**

?????????????????????????

???????????????????

????????php script to run the above program and output should be displayed on the webpage??????

???????????

????????

Comment: I would wrap the java in a shell script and then call it using php exec

Comment: i recommend you that can try out  phpjavabridge that might be pretty handy one to handle this kind offsituations

Comment: OP have not demonstrated any effort he performed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think that the best way to go is to expose the java code as web service 
and 'consume' it in php.
Check some tutorials on creating REST services from Java, I found this helpful

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/giqaa/index.html which shows how to do it in
Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jar with your java program and use php exec function for call this

```
<?php exec("java -jar sum1.jar num1 num2", $output); ?>
```

Comment: then try print_r($output) instead of echo($output)

Comment: It showing that Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from sum1.jar 1

Comment: You need to put a manifest.inf file in the root folder of your project. In this file you define the executable main class of your jar.